# How can I print my swap function with Struct

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Could you help me, how can I print my swap3 function? I would be very thankful.
I am beginner in programming

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pair{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Pair* swap3(const Pair& p){
    Pair *t = new Pair();
    t->x = p.y;
    t->y = p.x; 
    return t;
}

int main(){

    int f = Pair(2,3);
    swap3(f);
    cout<<f<<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Is my main function false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to overload `ostream` operator:

```
 friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Pair& pair) {
    os << pair.x << " " << pair.y << '\n';
    return os;
 }
```

If you are not comfortable with operator oveloading, you can simply print elements individually:

```
cout<< f.x <<" "<< f.y <<'\n';
```

---

The way you construct `f`, is wrong too (`int` and `Pair` are not the same type). You can try [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) instead:

```
Pair f{2,3};
auto s = swap3(f);
cout<<f<<endl;
delete s;
```

Note that you have memory leak in your code, because your function returns a pointer, you don't store it and you never delete it.

I recommend using smart pointers to avoid memory leak you had:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pair> swap3(const Pair& p){
    auto t = make_unique<Pair>(Pair{});
    t->x = p.y;
    t->y = p.x; 
    return t;
}
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j5SbEY)

P.S.
I am not sure what you want from swap, in the code you posted, you don't need a pointer at all. I think swap should be written like:

```
void swap3(Pair& p1, Pair& p2){
    Pair tmp{p1.x, p1.y};
    p1.x = p2.x;
    p1.y = p2.y;
    p2.x = tmp.x;
    p2.y = tmp.y;
}
```

or:

```
void swap3(Pair& p){
    Pair tmp{p.x, p.y};
    p.x = tmp.y;
    p.y = tmp.x;
}
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q5GR65)

Comment: I think recommending to print individual values is better than recommending to overload the ostream operator as the OP mentioned that he was a beginner.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that I cannot print it. We shouldn't use smart pointers and ostream in our task. I can change something only in my main function.

Comment: @JanylS then try cout<< f.x <<" "<< f.y <<'\n'; and don't forget to delete. Please also note that you don't need a pointer here. I can add an example without pointer if that helps.

Comment: @JanylS it is because you don't swap anything in the function. You just create a new object and return the new one which has the same numbers as the original one

Comment: mh, ok, thanks. But what does my swap3 function? t->x = p.y, t->y = p.x? I thought they swap x and y

Comment: @JanylS Sorry I just notice what you are trying to do. You swap and return a new object. and it is the new object that has swapped elements and the original one is unchanged(const Pair&). The problem is you don't store the swapped object anywhere. This code be what you want: https://godbolt.org/z/AXtWcp